# Multi Tenant architecture with schema per tenant limitation\problems

Tags: database, schema, multi-tenant, saas

In my scenario we have multi tenancy architecture and for data isolation we have one schema\tenant. eg if we have 1000 customers we are maintaining 1000 schemas. which is fast and maintaining the data isolation. but what is the limitation or what is the problem over shared schema having any unique identifier?

Comment: What does "schema" refer to in your question? If you mean "database schema" does that mean you use one database but each tenant gets their own tables? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, database schema. Having one database and each tenant has their own tables

Comment: That's an awfully general question. I suggest you do your homework and ask a more specific question giving more details on the scenario. As it stands you'd get unhelpful responses like "one problem is the vast amount of tables to be maintained".